# Дизайнер WPF автоматически отключает код проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

После переименования одного свойства в трех строках (1 в модели и 2 во вьюмодели) дизайнер стал отключать "Код проекта" каждый раз при его включении под предлогом "Для стабильности работы дизайнера".
Сам проект компилируется без проблем и привязки работают исправно.

[image]

Отключает он, если DataContext задан через форму:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:HomeViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

или

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:HomeViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

То есть, проблема должна быть во вьюмодели, но её конструктор как был пустым до ошибки, так таковым и остался.

А без отображения код вьюмодели мне такой дизайнер и не нужен, ибо верстать и привязывать данные вслепую - такая себе затея.

Очистка/пересборка/выгрузка проекта не помогла.
Переименование ранее упомянутого свойства на его прежнее имя не помогло.
Смена сборки не помогла.
Изменение версии фреймворка не помогло.
Советы из указываемой студией ссылки не помогли.

Какие еще есть варианты?

P.S. Через 10 минут стал выключать и с неуказанным датаконтекстом

Comment: `ибо верстать и привязывать данные вслепую - такая себе затея` - дам подсказку, запустили проект и пишете дизайн, в живую наблюдая как меняется дизайн приложения. `но её конструктор как был пустым до ошибки, так таковым и остался.` - а с чего вы взяли, что проблема в конструкторе? Это может быть свойство, которое выполняет сложную логику в своем `get`/`set`. `Через 10 минут стал выключать и с неуказанным датаконтекстом` - проверьте на чистом WPF проекте, если и там проблема, то у вас проблема в самой студии, либо вовсе железе.

Comment: Без кода не понять. Но выше комментарий вполне справедливый, где-то у вас тормоза.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я тоже могу дать подсказку: дизайнер работает и показывает изменения, но мне нужно отслеживать изменения, связанные с данными из вьюмодели. Как пример: верстка ItemTemplate. Можно было бы вводить туда текст-рыбу, а уже потом присмотреться, поменять отступы/размеры, и уже после этого всё заменять на биндинги, но этот метод из разряда "Пальцем в небо".

Comment: @aepot тормоза самой студии. Из совета выше проверил на чистом проекте: результат тот же. После перезагрузки сессии всё вернулось на круги своя. Проблема была даже не в геттерах и не сеттерах. Просто студия в очередной раз выдает краткосрочные баги